# Highcharts Areaspline - Highlight a column on hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Stuck with the problem of highlighting column of area spline. Didn't find any solutions via Chartjs, and Highcharts didn't help me either. I need to highlight x-axis column, but till the chart curve. In my code, I'm using Crosshair, but it's not exactly what I need.

```
xAxis: {
        allowDecimals:false,
        min: 1,
        max: 12,
        categories: ['', 'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC', ''],
        labels: {
            y: -10,
            style: {
                color: '#66717c',
                fontSize: '13px'
            }
        },
        tickWidth: 0,
        lineColor: "#fff",
        crosshair: {
            width: 60,
            color: 'rgba(73,168,222,0.5)',
            zIndex: 5
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        gridLineWidth: '0',
        visible: false
    }
```

My result:

[image: Img01]

And what I need:

[image: Img02]

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will add another series that will be stacked on top of the real series with percent stacking, then you could use that area fill is partially transparent and place `crosshair` under series. Fake series should be used as something to cover part of the `crosshair` that you want to hide.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aft9esqr/