# How can I create the below chart combination of line and column using highchart

Tags: highcharts

How can I create the below chart combination of line and column using highchart
[image]

Comment: You can achieve a similar effect using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610669/highcharts-areaspline-highlight-a-column-on-hover-effect. However, this might not cover all your requirements. This type of chart is not available directly from the API and would require significant customization, which is beyond the scope of my support. You can attempt to customize it yourself by extending Highcharts methods as outlined here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts. You can also create a feature request on the Highcharts GitHub page.